# What methods are available to execute things in the background

Tags: android, multithreading, background

My question is short and simple.

What are the different methods are available to execute things in the background, and what is the pros and cons for them?

I've used a few, like Thread, AsyncTask, TimerTask, Serivce, Service in other process, but
i don't know what their pros and cons are.

Comment: [Best Practices for Background Jobs](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html)

Comment: Thanks, but from what i can see, that link don't contain any info about threads, AsyncTask, and what have you, or their pros and cons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AsyncTasks for small tasks. if you want to do something periodic, like checking for updates every x sec, use background services (background Services can run even when youre app is closed, but don't have to).

Look here, that's a great explanation and tutorial for Asynctasks and threads:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: Thanks! That site also explained the disadvantages of some of the approaches. Just that I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) - Useful for simple tasks to be completed in the background. Often used to start a new Thread with the "Fire and Forget" mindset.

[Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) - Useful for when there is a process with several steps, or needs to run forever in the background.

[TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) - Useful for tasks that need to execute on a time based schedule.

[Android Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) - These share the main thread of application.  Services are basically an Activity without a layout.  Used to run processes in the background throughout the life of the application or activity, but needs to spawn their own thread for any heavy lifting.